# Problema al migrar sitios entre servidores Plesk

Tags: migration, plesk

Hago esta pregunta para tratar de resolver un problema que tengo hace más de 3 meses.

Comenzaré dando detalles de ambos servidores.

**Servidor de origen** : 17.8.11 Actualización # 40

**Servidor de destino** : 17.8.11 Actualización # 40

He intentado dos formas de realizar la migración:

1- Usando la migración normal, traté de mover varios sitios. Después de una espera de más de 30 minutos, Plesk me mostró un mensaje de error. (No tengo este mensaje de error, pero es el mismo que voy a mostrar más adelante).

2- Creé una copia de seguridad en el servidor de origen, luego descargué esa copia de seguridad y, al cargarla en el servidor de destino, encontré el siguiente error:

**Información extra:**

He hecho clic en las siguientes opciones:
* Subir archivos de copia de seguridad sin una firma válida
* Usar protección por contraseña (recomendado)

**Error:**

[Error acá](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdKGf.png)

Sé que las copias de seguridad del servidor de destino se guardan en un disco compartido con otros servidores, tal vez el sistema de archivos de ese disco sea diferente al disco del servidor de origen. Aunque no sé mucho sobre el tema, el tema supera mi nivel de conocimiento.

¿Puedes ayudarme por favor?

Lo ideal sería resolver el error de migración, pero si hay una solución parcial (que debo aplicar a cada copia de seguridad.tar manualmente) me sirve lo mismo.

Creo que el error también se debe a la identificación de los usuarios, ¿cómo podría hacer un mapeo de los usuarios?